# How do I use BLE module and RFM69 module together?

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, ble

I am trying to use an Adafruit BLE module and an RFM69 module on the same Arduino.

The higher-level functions in each included library (Adafruit_BLE.h, RFM69.h) both use the SPI.h library to talk to each respective module.

I think all I need to do is make a copy of the SPI.h file, and edit it to make the SS pin for one of the modules different.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The SS pin will be defined by the target device library, not SPI.h. Check the options for the constructor in each library for how to change the SS pin from your own code.

Comment: you mean like Arduino.h?

Comment: No, I mean like RFM69.h or Adafruit_BLE.h or whatever the libraries are called that you are using.